# phpunit method viaRemember doesnt exist - laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

i am using laravel and php unit test, every time i ran the unit test it always show errors like this, i went deep through the framework and found nothing.

can somebody help? its so frustrating, thanks

here's the error looks like

> PHPUnit 5.7.26 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.
>
> 1)
>   Tests\Feature\CreateCitiesTest::an_authenticated_user_can_create_a_city
>   BadMethodCallException: Method viaRemember does not exist.

Found it! thanks!
commenting this line in kernel.php, i think i inserted this and i dont what is the function hehehe

> ```
>         // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
> ```

Comment: How does your `app/Http/Kernel.php` looks like ?

Comment: what was returned from viaRemember? Are you tried debug?

Comment: @JeuneGuerrier here is my http/kernel sir https://pastebin.com/m4gThvSF

Comment: @AliÖzen i dont know, i am new using laravel im really sorry. could you tell me how to debug it?